# Counting embedded documents in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, aggregation-framework

I am using Rails + Mongoid and I have 3 models setup like so:

```
# sheet.rb
class Sheet
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  embeds_many :rows
end

# row.rb
class Row
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  embedded_in :sheet
  embeds_many :cells
end

# cell.rb
class Cell
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :display_value, type: String
  field :column_id, type: String
  field :active, type: Mongoid::Boolean

  embedded_in :row
end
```

Here is an example sheet document (JSON):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57100b713ab82964c3c17ecb"),
    "name" : "Ship Tracker",
  "rows": [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57100b813ab82964c3c17f54"),
      "name": "Obelisk"
        "cells" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57100b813ab82964c3c17f55"),
                "column_id": "7263313013827459",
                "display_value" : "Undocked",
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57100b813ab82964c3c17f76"),
                "column_id" : "7263313013827460",
                "display_value" : "J7X-VN",
                "active": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57100b813ab82964c3c18e3a"),
      "name": "Thanatos"
        "cells" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57100b813ab82964c3c17f6e"),
                "column_id": "7263313013827459",
                "display_value" : "Undocked",
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57100b813ab82964c3c17f70"),
                "column_id" : "7263313013827460",
                "display_value" : "NHKO-4",
                "active": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57100b813ab82964c3c17f47"),
      "name": "Brutix"
        "cells" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57100b813ab82964c3c17f66"),
                "column_id": "7263313013827459",
                "display_value" : "Docked",
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57100b813ab82964c3c17f3c"),
                "column_id" : "7263313013827460",
                "display_value" : "P-T9VC",
                "active": true
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying, but failing, to return a count of display values.  I have tried using the aggregation framework with Mongoid but it does not seems to return any results.

I am using the following code to aggregate but I feel like I am doing something wrong.  I am not getting any errors back from Mongoid/Ruby:

```
 query = [{'$match': {'$rows.$cells.active': true}},
        {'$group': {'_id': '$rows.$cells.display_value', 'total': {'$sum': '$amount'}}}]
 sheet = Sheet.first
 results = sheet.collection.aggregate(query)
```

When I inspect the results it returns a `Mongo::Collection::View::Aggregation` object and I can not figure out what to do with this.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. A few pointers to start:

1) #collection goes to the collection object for that class. So Sheet.collection is the same as sheet.first.collection. It is a handle for the whole collection of documents.

2) The aggregation is only run when it is called to output. Put a .each{|l| p l } and you'll see it puke out the results

3) An aggregation can be made up of unlimited number of manipulations. The array that is pass into the aggregation is executed in the order you send it in. So [project, match, sort] will return a different set of results to [match, sort, project]. You can build up and output your layers as you go along to ensure you have built it correctly.

4) You'll need to unwind your embedded documents to do the count you wish (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).

If you need me to write the aggregation for you, I can, but it's a good exercise to go through the motions of building it yourself. You'll find all the info you need for it on the mongodb site. Shout if you need any help.

Comment: Nice. This was perfect. I managed to get what I needed. The unwind operator is what I was looking for.  It was indeed a good learning exercise. Thanks, mate.